# What code in Spring handles the loading of @Configuration properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a legacy Spring based project that initially was based off spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.10.
In the project there is a class declared as

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "redis")
public class MyRedisConfiguration extends org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport {
    private String hostName;
    private int port;
    private String password;

    public void setHostName(String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    [... etc ...]
}
```

With Spring 2.7.10 it worked fine.

After upgrading to Spring 2.7.18, property values are no longer initialized from the profile settings.
Other configuration classes are initilized fine, but not this one.

The main application class is declared as

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "30m")
@EnableRetry(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"my"})
@ComponentScan(value={"my"})
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(value={"my"})
public class MyMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure (SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyMain.class);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        [...]
        ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(MyMain.class, args);
        [...]
```

Adding

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(value={"my"})
```

did not help, property values are still not loaded into MyRedisConfiguration.

Enabling

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.core.io.support: 'DEBUG'
    org.springframework.context.annotation: 'DEBUG'
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure: 'DEBUG'
```

did not reveal anything remarkable: class MyRedisConfiguration is duly mentioned, but the properties are still not loaded.

I'd like to debug Spring to see why they are not loaded, but Spring is fairly humongous.

Exactly what code in Spring is responsible for initialization of classes annotated @Configuration/@ConfigurationProperties ?

Comment: could you please edit your question and add your `@SpringBootApplication` class?

Comment: Just added the essential class outline.

Comment: @sergey_o looks like you just need to add `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to your `MyMain` class, you can drop the `ConfigurationPropertiesScan`.  `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyRedisConfiguration.class)`.  Also, if MyRedisConfiguration is just a PoJo, you can drop the `@Configuration` from it.

Comment: I tracked down what happens. Property setters do get eventually invoked. However in 2.7.10 they get invoked before at-Bean methods, and in 2.7.18 they get invoked AFTER Bean methods. Since Bean methods use config property values to construct beans, this of course breaks everything. Looks like there was a major bug introduced in Spring somewhere between these two versions?

Comment: The problem is you don't have `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyRedisConfiguration.class` and also that it also acts like an `@Configuration`. It is one or the other not both.

Comment: You also have a ton of annotations on it which shouldn't be there on your `@SpringBootApplication` class. Like `@ComponentScan`, `@EnableJpaRepositories` etc.

Comment: I am unsure why you suggest "not both". Googling for "@Configuration @ConfigurationProperties" brings tons of examples and guides where it is exactly both. 

Ditto for "@SpringBootApplication @ComponentScan". 

If I use explicit EnableConfigurationProperties(MyRedisConfiguration.class), this creates an extra instance (two instances instead of one) and causes Spring startup to abort.